# Should I use list() or wrap in brackets?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

If I have a nested dictionary and I want to make a value into a list and add to it, should I do this

```
mydict[my_key][my_value] = [mydict[my_key][my_value]].append(new_value)
```

or this

```
mydict[my_key][my_value] = list(mydict[my_key][my_value]).append(new_value)
```

The structure looks like:

```
{'foo': {'bar': 'hi'}}
```

and I want:

```
{'foo': {'bar': ['hi', 'bye']}}
```

Comment: Is "neither" an option?

Comment: Definitely. Do go on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not do either one.

`list.append` works in-place and always returns `None`.  So, `mydict[my_key][my_value]` will be assigned to `None` after Python executes either of those lines.

You need to call `list.append` on its own line:

```
mydict[my_key][my_value] = [mydict[my_key][my_value]]
mydict[my_key][my_value].append(new_value)
```

Also, `list()` and `[]` are two different things.

- Putting `mydict[my_key][my_value]` in square brackets makes a one-item list where `mydict[my_key][my_value]` is the item.
- Using `list()` however tells Python to iterate over `mydict[my_key][my_value]` and collect its items into a list.  Moreover, a `TypeError` will be raised if `mydict[my_key][my_value]` is not iterable.

Below is a demonstration of what I said above:

```
>>> tup = (1, 2, 3)
>>> [tup]      # Places tup in a list
[(1, 2, 3)]
>>> list(tup)  # Makes tup into a list
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
>>> [1]
[1]
>>> list(1)  # Integers are not iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>>
```

Comment: `mydict[my_key][my_value].append(new_value)` returns `AttributeError`

Comment: That's because you haven't made `mydict[my_key][my_value]` a list yet.  I do not know the exact nature of your data, so I cannot tell you whether to use `list()` or `[]`.  Basically, you should use `list()` if you want Python to iterate over `mydict[my_key][my_value]` and collect its items into a list.  Otherwise, use `[mydict[my_key][my_value]]` to have Python place `mydict[my_key][my_value]` in a list.

Comment: That was my original question, I muddied it up with the `.append()` nonsense. You should change the `...` part of your answer to `[mydict[my_key][my_value]]` so that it's clear how to solve it.

Comment: Done.  I did `...` before because I didn't know what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list for each dict element, use `defaultdict``

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydict = defaultdict(list)
mydict[some_key].append(new_value)
```

Comment: I don't need one for each dict element, just values that happen to share a key.

Comment: You __need__ a list for each entry, because you don't want to write code, that tests, if there is more than one.

Comment: So `if type(mydict['foo']['bar']) == list` is too much code?

Comment: I suppose you're right. I'll make every nested value into a list to keep it uniform.

Comment: Actually I have to use `if/else` because I'm building this dict on the fly. Once it is completed I will go through and make nested dict values into lists.